# Legend Scrollbar Issue

Tags: silverlight, teechart

I'm facing an issue with the Legend Scroll bar.

When we Scroll, Bar thumb overlaps with up and down scroll arrows.

Is there any property or any other work around to fix it?
Please find the attached screenshot.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBEP2.png)
[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tHsG.png)

Comment: We'd need more info please. What TeeChart version are you using? Can you arrange a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I am using teechart.silverlight v4.1.2012.1033. Also, Added another screenshot (screenshot2) for reference on the above post.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. Have you tried if the current release (v4.1.2016.05120) still reproduces the problem for you? If it still reproduces the problem, please try to arrange a simple example project we can run as-is to reproduce the problem here.